# LINQ :Maintain "var" state across method calls?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, methods, threadpool

Okay, so I am using linq and thus I have a few "var" types object created dynamically, as in

> var Order = CustomerDataContext.Order.Where(e => e.OrderPending)

and many others like this, so the problem is how can I maintain this "var" across method calls, I am using
`ThreadPool.QueueUserForWorkItem(ProcessOrder, var)` but this method accepts object and I cannot cast the back in parameter back into `Order` type. Also, since its `var` it cannot even be declared as static, so that I may maintain state, so what should I do? How should I maintain this `var`, or if I cannot, then what is the other way to do what I am doing?

Comment: ps: read the comments posted to Kamyar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

> [var] An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

You don't maintain `var` type. in your sample, the `Order` is probably of type `IQueryable`. var is just a shortcut so you don't have to specify the type of variable and let the compiler do it. So you could've just written:

```
IQueryable<Order> Order = CustomerDataContext.Order.Where(e => e.OrderPending)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you fully understood my point. I know I could have very well used Order or any other arbitrary valid string token. But the point is, after I filter, Just like you did in your expression, and pass this **filtered** record to some other method, how do you get its state back, if the method expects an argument of type object, as you cannot convert it into `Order` type because that var (or order as you said it) was just local variable to the caller function.

Comment: We can still create a new Order, but that would destroy the whole purpose of filtering some records and then passing those records to another method to be processed? If we create a new `Order` in other method say, `ProcessOrder` in this case, it will be a new `Order` type and not the one filtered on some condition and passed to this method.
I hope I made my point clear this time, if I was vague previously...

Comment: I am really if I am unable to make this clear enough, but this did not worked, but really thanks for trying..